# Access props object properties Vue 3 + TS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm having trouble accessing the properties of my sent object from my parent component.
In my child component, I would like to access `"found"` in the object `"lettersState"` (see code below). When I try to access `"found"` in my child component. refer the error message

> Property 'found' does not exist on type 'Object'.

**parent component :**

```js
const state = reactive({
  guesses: ['', '', '', '', '', ''],
  solution: '',
  currentRow: 0,
  lettersState: {
    found: [] as string[],
    miss: [] as string[],
    hint: [] as string[],
  }
})
```

```js
<template>
  <Keyboard @handleKeyboard="handleKeyboard" :lettersState="state.lettersState" />
</template>
```

**child :**

```js
const props = defineProps<{lettersState:Object}>()
console.log(props.lettersState.found)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const props = defineProps<{lettersState:Object}>()
```

tells typescript that your props look like this:

```
{
  lettersState: {}
}
```

But looking at `:lettersState="state.lettersState"` you want it to be:

```
type LetterState = {
  found: string[]
  miss: string[]
  hint: string[]
}
const props = defineProps<{letterState: LetterState}>()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `:lettersState="state.lettersState"`, and then you access `console.log(props.lettersState.found)`. If you look closer, you can see that `letterState` does not exist in what you passed as a prop: You only passed the value corresponding to `letterState`. Therefore, there is no need to access the `letterState` key. Try this:

```
const props = defineProps<{
    found: string[],
    miss: string[],
    hint: string[]
  }>()
console.log(props.found)
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do that, thanks for the answer !